# Allow non-SELECT permission user to run MySQL stored procedure which has SELECT query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two MySQL users:

- mysql_user_1
- mysql_user_2 (EXECUTE permission only)

mysql_user_1 created a stored procedure `getRecord(int uid_of_record)` which run a `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE uid=?`. Can `mysql_user_2` execute that stored procedure without having `SELECT` privilege?

Comment: Did you try it and find out?

Comment: @tadman Barmar's answer is perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in detail in the MySQL documentation [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html).

A stored procedure can be defined with either:

```
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

or

```
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

If it's `DEFINER`, the procedure executes with the permissions of the user who defined the procedure; in your case, if `mysql_user_1` has `SELECT` privilege, the procedure will work for `mysql_user_2`.

If it's `INVOKER`, the procedure executes with the permissions of the user running the procedure. The procedure won't work for `mysql_user_2` in this case.

If you don't have this clause in the procedure, it defaults to `DEFINER`.